# Create new object best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There are times I instantiate a new object within a method call for sake of streamlining code instead of assigning the new object to a variable.  What drawbacks exist in doing one or the other?

```
T myobj = new T();
elements.Add(myobj);
```

--vs--

```
elements.Add(new T());
```

Comment: You would be very hard pressed to find an example where this matters whatsoever. I'm unsure why you're wasting your time pondering this unless there's an actual issue present. You may be trying to solve a problem that doesn't even exist. 2nd is more concise IMO but that's it really. The only reason I'd do the first is simply if you need to -- we don't know what your use case is so we can't really say.

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this as "primarily opinion based." as there are some demonstrable differences between the two.

Comment: @mason Because the question is "best practices"..

Comment: With the first method, you are creating a reference for the object which may come in handy at a latter date

Comment: If you're going to use the object right away, the first way will make that easier. Performance wise, no difference.

Comment: @user2864740 But the question itself asks for drawbacks. Clearly the best practices are going to be derived from the drawbacks/advantages of using one over the other, making this question *not* primarily opinion based.

Comment: LOL ^^ - but seriously there is no difference at all.  Declaring the object first as a variable might be more readable and is also required if you need to do something else with it, ither than adding it to a list, as in your example.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @mason What demonstrable difference? (Outside of Debug builds) Using the variable later must be discarded as an argument because it applies in only one case.

Comment: @adaam There are the same number of "references" (but just think objects) created in either case - and it is accessible later in both cases.

Comment: @user2864740 Not by name. I don't really know what you're trying to get at..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Need a reference later

As adaam mentioned in the comments, if you need to keep a reference to an object because you'll be using it, then it's better to do it this way.

```
T myobj = new T();
elements.Add(myobj);
T.DoStuff(); //this might need to happen further down in the code, so keeping the reference is handy. Otherwise we'd have to dig it out of the elements. And you might be thinking "well, I don't need to reference it later in the code." But what if you're refactoring the code and it requires some modification? Now you'll need to change it, rather than having done it with a separate declaration in the first place.
```

## Debugging

A common situation is when you're stepping through code with the debugger. It's difficult to see properties of an object that was created in this manner.

```
elements.Add(new T());
```

When given its own reference, you can easily use your IDE's debugging tools to check the values if the code is written like this:

```
T myobj = new T();
elements.Add(myobj);
```

## Readability

Another reason to choose one over the other would be readability. That one is opinion based, but you should ask the team you're working with which is more readable in order to determine which practice to follow. Asking everyone on Stack Overflow which reads better is off topic.

Comment: If the author wished to access the object directly (as opposed to via the collection) later, this question would not exist - a variable would be used. Thus, I don't believe this is a valid demonstrable difference.

Comment: @user2864740 It is a demonstrable difference. I've got two reasons now why one would be preferable over the other. The question does exist, and it's not opinion based, so it makes sense to try to answer it with any differences we can think of.

Comment: I do not find this a *relevant* demonstrable difference because the concept does not come up in the question. If one needs immediate access to an object, then one would use a variable and there would be no question here - that is, the question only exists in context of a temporary variable not used elsewhere in code. Also, both cases "keep a reference" as seen in a case like `elements.Add(new T()); elements.Last().DoStuff().` (The argument for a variable would be much better here, *but* that case does not come up in this question.)

Comment: The question asked what the drawbacks are. One of the drawbacks is that you need to then retrieve a reference to the object if you later want to do something with it. I know he didn't mention that in the question, but it's still part of the answer because it partially answers the question.

Comment: *That drawback does not exist in context, because the operation is not performed in the question.* For the same reason, the advantage of a variable does not exist in the context of the question.

Comment: @user2864740 It doesn't have to be performed in the question in order to be included in the answer. I get it that you don't like it, but you've made your point known and still continuing to repeat it. That's just mucking up the question and answer.

Comment: *Primary* answers should be *relevant* to the question. I find that the "demonstrable difference" answer is not relevant for the reasons given above. For instance, say I ask "Is it better to use obj.ToString("X") or string.Format("{0:X}", obj)?" While perhaps useful as *part* of a reply, an answer that *hinges* on "string.Format can handle multiple values" is *irrelevant* (and should be common knowledge), because there is only value in question. Context matters.

Comment: @user2864740 The answer is relevant to the question. The question asked for a list of drawbacks of using one technique over the other. If you want to say it's not relevant, you must explain *why* rather than inventing other hypothetical straw men that are unrelated to my answer. If you feel that you've already said *why* then perhaps it's time to stop commenting since your point has been expressed.

Comment: @user2864740 Reading through this thread, I find your behaviour to be very abrasive - you're spinning the meaning of the OP's original question to match what you think the question is about, just as much as mason was or I was when we posted our original comments. My ==>OPINION<== is that he originally asked the question with the view of promoting an open discussion, which you have very dictatorially shut down.

Comment: @adaam I'm simply not adding additional information. I think it is more abrasive to attack me, than for me to "attack" information provided.

Comment: I was simply looking for opinions and whether instantiating an object directly in a method call was a 'no-no'.  I awarded the correct answer above since it shows the two trains of thought and why a reference to the variable may be desired.

Comment: @joeldow Your question is good, but your question title and above comment make it sound like you're asking for opinions. It's okay to ask for the differences, and then draw your own conclusions from those differences. It is not okay to ask for opinions, which would be off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @mason. I shouldn't have used the word 'opinion' above.  I know both techniques work, but didn't know if there was a reason to avoid the latter.